# \DeclareMathOperator adds spaces after the periods contained in its second argument (name text)

Tags: spacing, amsmath, math-operators, operator-space

The following MCE points out that `\DeclareMathOperator`, if its second argument (name text) contains periods, adds spaces after those periods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\DeclareMathOperator{\limone}{l.i.m.}
\newcommand\limtwo{\mathop{\mathrm{l.i.m.}}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A_t & =\limone A_{n,t} \\
  A_t & =\limtwo A_{n,t} \\
  A_t & =\text{l.i.m.} A_{n,t}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you know why and how to get rid of these spaces?

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator{\limone}{l{.}i{.}m{.}}`  Note that while the `l.i.m.` will still line up with your `\text` case, there will be a gap following the last `.`, because `l.i.m.` is now an operator, whereas `\text{l.i.m.}` is a math atom.

Comment: Using `{.} `? Untested, it just makes the dot an ord. Which math operator is that? Never seen one with punctuation in it before

Comment: @daleif `{.}` works nicely indeed. Concerning the operator, some authors use it for denoting the convergence in the mean square sense. I agree it is quite strange :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare with

```
$l\mathpunct{.}i\mathpunct{.}m$
```

Indeed, your `\limone` gives `\qopname \newmcodes@ o{l.i.m.}` and `\newmcodes` assigns `\mathpunct` category to the dot (which will be taken in *letters* font, not *operators*...). Another strangeness of `\newmcodes@`.

```
\newmcodes@ ->\mathcode `\'39\mathcode `\*42\mathcode `\."613A\ifnum \mathcode 
`\-=45 \else \mathchardef \std@minus \mathcode `\-\relax \fi \mathcode `\-45\ma
thcode `\/47\mathcode `\:"603A\relax
```

You will have same `\mathpunct` spacing with `:`. [image]

What to do? You can always define your own `\newmcodes@` to replace above definition.

Comment: Define my own `\newmcodes@`?! Are you kidding me? :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I knew that would keep you busy while I went to watch cartoons on replay-tv `;-)`. Try `\let\newmcodes@\relax` or ok if you want it more politically correct, copy above (beware linebreaks) removing the `6` in `"613A"`

Comment: I guess that when the code for `\qopname` was being developed by Spivak and the AMS (it went essentially unchanged into `amsmath.sty` from `amstex.tex`) the use cases dictated that the period had to be considered as punctuation in an operator name.

Comment: @egreg you are right, surely. I wonder what kind of use cases, and why one would treat an operator name like a piece of text.

Answer (score 5):

`\DeclareMathOperator{\limone}{l{.}i{.}m{.}}` will fix the excess space in row 1, making it like row 2. Note that while the `l.i.m.` will still line up with your `\text` case, there will be a gap following the last `.`, because `l.i.m.` (in the form of `\limone` or `\limtwo`) is now an operator, whereas `\text{l.i.m.}` is a math atom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\DeclareMathOperator{\limone}{l{.}i{.}m{.}}
\newcommand\limtwo{\mathop{\mathrm{l.i.m.}}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A_t & =\limone A_{n,t} \\
  A_t & =\limtwo A_{n,t} \\
  A_t & =\text{l.i.m.} A_{n,t}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does the trick, indeed. But why this behaviour without the braces? And agree with your note (I added the `\text` example in order to show the spaces with `\DeclareMathOperator` didn't come from a possible underlying "text" mode).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Not sure, but it may be related to this: `\gdef\newmcodes@{\mathcode\`\'39\mathcode``\*42\mathcode``\."613A%
 \mathcode``\-45\mathcode``\/47\mathcode``\:"603A\relax}`, declared in `amstex.sty`.